# Windows shell script exit child processes on shell close?

Tags: windows, shell, windows-shell

I have the following bash script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    exec node web/dist/web/src/app.js 1>&1 2>&1 &
    exec node api/dist/api/src/app.js 1>&1 2>&1 &
    $SHELL
```

It runs both my node processes, routing STDOUT and STDERR to my current window.
However, when I close the terminal window, or hit (CTRL+C) It **doesn't kill my child processe**s, how can I configure this?

Comment: Not sure about the behavour of Windows. In Unix if the child process is ignoring HUP (=HangUp) signal, then the background process will not die if the parent is gone. Either the child process has to acitvely act on HUP-signal, or you have to capture the background PID (via $!) and send a `kill` in your EXIT trap.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'kill 0' EXIT

exec node web/dist/web/src/app.js 1>&1 2>&1 &
exec node api/dist/api/src/app.js 1>&1 2>&1 &

wait
```

Comment: Hey thanks, have tried that, still doesn't seem to work.